# how to convert a txt file to a array python. "could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, numpy

I need to import a array value of a txt file but when i print to see my values i get this error: "could not convert string to float: vector(0.1013, 0.2395, 1.1926), vector(0.1276, 0.2361, 1.1760), vector(0.13952644965926353, 0.23617897201269641, 1.1760001652770353), vector(0.16723382973344353, 0.23617897201269641, 1.176000165277035"
showing only a few values of the array.
Any idea as to what I am doing wrong and what would be the correct way to do it ?

```
def load_files(self):

    dlg = wx.FileDialog(None,message="Choose File",wildcard= 'Points (*.txt; *.csv)|*.txt;*.csv', defaultFile="",style=wx.FD_OPEN|wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST|wx.FD_CHANGE_DIR)

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            print ('buh cancelaste')

    else:


        filename=dlg.GetFilename()
        f = open(filename)
        data = f.read()
        data = np.array(data).astype(float)
        print(data)


files = wx.Button(pan, label='Load Coordinates', pos=(x1+158,570), size = (150,40))
files.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, load_files)
```

txt file.

vector(0.1013, 0.2395, 1.1926), vector(0.1276, 0.2361, 1.1760),                      vector(0.13952644965926353, 0.23617897201269641, 1.1760001652770353), vector(0.16723382973344353, 0.23617897201269641, 1.1760001652770353), vector(0.18306661834726065, 0.23617897201269641, 1.1760001652770353), vector(0.21077399842144068, 0.23219954535704859, 1.1760001652770353), vector(0.22264858988180353, 0.22822011870140083, 1.1760001652770353), vector(0.23452318134216635, 0.22822011870140083, 1.1760001652770353)

vector(-3.22925576,  0.78085742,  8.2709313 ), vector(0.12270437,  0.29943441,  1.65709467), vector(0.1278586, 0.09019178,  1.24548948), vector(0.25600214, -0.04258577,  0.6109198)

vector(0.12795994,  0.30532043,  1.6896684 ), vector( 0.13624277,  0.09229906,  1.24548948), vector(0.29656594, -0.08827312,  0.69378916), vector (0.19870717, -0.09120946,  1.19266453)

Comment: Try using numpy.loadtxt (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) - will have to convert the imput file it only contains numbers and commas (if delimiter=',').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that `data` as passed to `np.array` is one or more strings of the form

```
vector(0.1013, 0.2395, 1.1926), vector(0.1276, 0.2361, 1.1760), vector(0.13952644965926353, 0.23617897201269641, 1.1760001652770353), vector(0.16723382973344353, 0.23617897201269641, 1.176000165277035
```

One long string.  You did nothing to break it up on spaces, commas or even newlines.

With `astype(float)` you are trying to convert that string to a float, or sequence of floats.  The Python `float(astr)` function works with strings like `"0.1013"`, not long ones with many numbers.  Even if you broke the `data` into  substrings like

```
vector(0.1013, 0.2395, 1.1926)
```

it would have problems, because `vector` means nothing.

You need to do more parsing of those file lines.  You need to split them into lines (e.g. `readline()`), strip off `\n`, split them up into blocks like `vector()`, and further split that into strings with one number each.  In other words, a list of strings like this will work:

```
In [848]: np.array(['0.1013', '0.2395', '1.1926'])
Out[848]: 
array(['0.1013', '0.2395', '1.1926'], 
      dtype='<U6')

In [849]: np.array(['0.1013', '0.2395', '1.1926']).astype(float)
Out[849]: array([ 0.1013,  0.2395,  1.1926])
```

---

Observe what happens when `data` is that 'vector()' string:

```
In [852]: np.array('vector(0.1013, 0.2395, 1.1926)')
Out[852]: 
array('vector(0.1013, 0.2395, 1.1926)', 
      dtype='<U30')

In [853]: np.array('vector(0.1013, 0.2395, 1.1926)').astype(float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-853-413e30b24430> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array('vector(0.1013, 0.2395, 1.1926)').astype(float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'vector(0.1013, 0.2395, 1.1926)'
```

`astype(float)` does not search the string(s) for substrings that look like numbers.  Try `float('123 45')` and variations.  `float()` needs something that looks exactly like a float or integer.